# Prime number check java

Tags: java, numbers

Write a program to read n numbers. The first number specified as input will be n. Next, the program should read n integer numbers.

The program should check for each number if it is prime as well as if its reverse is prime.

Display all such numbers in ascending order.

Consider below example for input and output:

Input:
7
11
12
23
19
7
113
101

Output:

7
11
101
113

My code

```
public class Prime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        int temp;

        int[] a = new int [x];
        int[] r = new int [x];
        int[]c = new int[a.length+r.length];
        int[] rev = new int [x];

        for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
            rev[i]=a[i];
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            while(rev[i] != 0) {
                r[i] = r[i] * 10;
                r[i] = r[i] + rev[i]%10;
                rev[i] = rev[i]/10;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            boolean isPrime = true;
            for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
                if((a[i]%j==0) || (r[i]%j==0)) {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(isPrime) 
                System.out.println(a[i]);
            System.out.println(r[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Somewhere I am stuck I don't know how to eliminate repeated no,  how to merge the array at last and also it is printing 1 and 2 as prime no when I give input  and 2

Comment: To eliminate duplicates , use a `Set`

Comment: i dont know how to use it I am beigner

Comment: Please show what you have tried, and why exactly it didn't work, in the smallest amount of code possible. We're here to help you solve a specific problem, not write your code for you.

Comment: Try breaking down the problem into smaller chunks. I recommend making a few methods which each handle a small portion of the program. You can then test each of them individually. First make a method to check if a number is prime `boolean isPrime(int i)`, then make method to reverse the number, `int reverse(int i)`. Create a method `boolean isReversePrime(int i)` which calls both `isPrime(i)` and `isPrime(reverse(i))`, etc etc. Breaking down a problem into smaller steps may look like more work, but it makes your code much easier to read and also much easier to verify the correctness.

Comment: @tyler - Since you are a beginner, I suggest you read the javadocs for the `Set` interface and the `TreeSet` class.

Comment: Instead of checking till n, we can check till √n because a larger factor of n must be a multiple of smaller factor which all ready cover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use TreeSet - which will contain only distinct elements and  give result in sorted form. You can refer to following code-

```
  Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                boolean isPrime = true;
                if(isPrime(a[i]) && isPrime(r[i]))
                    set.add(a[i]);
            }
Iterator it = set.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
            System.out.print(it.next() + " ");
```

Also create a function for checking prime numbers -

```
private static boolean isPrime(int num) {
        if(num==1) return false;
        for(int i = 2; i <= num/2; ++i)
        {
            if(num % i == 0)
            {
               return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: how to print output in as shown in question in that format as after converting to set it is not printing in that format

Comment: Modified code to print output. Also, read javadocs for set , treeset , iterators and other collections.

Comment: it is printing 1 also as prime

Comment: Tyler , you need to add base cases yourself.In this case from your isPrime function add a condition to return false if num == 1

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code. Hope it helps you,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class PrimeNumberTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(7, 11, 12, 23, 19, 7 ,113, 101)); 
         //To remove duplicates
         Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>(list);
         System.out.println(getPrimeNumbers(set).toString().replaceAll(",", "").replace("]", "").replace("[", ""));
    }
    //Method to get unique ordered set of prime numbers
    private static Set<Integer> getPrimeNumbers(Set<Integer> set) {
        Set<Integer> resultList=new TreeSet<>();
        set.forEach(ele->{
            //check for prime
            if(isPrime(ele)){
                //if prime number check for reverse and if true, add to result
                 if(isPrime(reverserNumb(ele)))
                     resultList.add(ele);
            }
        });
        return resultList;
    }

    private static boolean isPrime(int num){
        if(num<2)
            return false;
        // Check for even numbers
        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            return num == 2;
        }
      // Check for odd numbers
        for (int i = 3; i*i <= num; i += 2) {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    private static int reverserNumb(int num) {
        return Integer.valueOf(new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(num)).reverse().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for prime test using √n approach

```
static boolean isPrime(int n){
//corner case
if (n <= 1) return false; 
if (n <= 3) return true; 
//middle 5 number
if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0) return false;
for (int i = 5; i * i <= n; i = i + 6) 
            if (n % i == 0 || n % (i + 2) == 0) 
            return false;  
return true;
}
```

Use can use `set` for remove duplicate element

Answer (score 0):

Try if this code works, hope it helps

**Code:**

```
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.Collections;
        import java.util.Scanner;

        public class PrimeNumbers {

            static ArrayList<Integer> prime = new ArrayList<>(); 
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("Enter Number of Integers: ");
                int number_count = user_input.nextInt();
                int[] numbers = new int[number_count];
                for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                    System.out.print("Enter Integer: ");
                    numbers[i] = user_input.nextInt();
                }

                System.out.print("Values Entered: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                    System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");
                    checkPrime(numbers[i],false); //false don't reverse
                    checkPrime(numbers[i],true); //true reverse value to check if it is also prime
                }

                System.out.print("\nList of prime numbers: ");
                Collections.sort(prime);
                for(int n : prime){
                    System.out.print(n + " ");
                }
                if(prime.isEmpty()){
                    System.out.print("no prime numbers on list\n");
                }
            }

            //check for duplicates
            static void insertValueToPrime(int n){
                for(int p : prime){
                    if(n == p){
                        return;
                    }
                }
                prime.add(n);
            }


            static void checkPrime(int n,boolean isReverse) {
                int i, m = 0, flag = 0,realn = n;
                if(isReverse){
                    n = reverseNumber(n);
                }
                m = n / 2;
                if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
                    //no a prime number
                } else {
                    for (i = 2; i <= m; i++) {
                        if (n % i == 0) {
        //                    not a prime number
                            flag = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (flag == 0) {
                        insertValueToPrime(realn);
                    }
                }
            }

            static int reverseNumber(int n){
                String reverse = "",str=""+n;
                for(int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    reverse = reverse + str.charAt(i);
                }
                return Integer.parseInt(reverse);
            }

        }
```

Comment: your code is working properly but it is not passing the test case that is if 19 and 91 both are prime then only it should print 19

Comment: I tried entering 19 & 91 and prints only 19. could you please elaborate it even more, I could have misunderstood you

Comment: try the test case given in input your output will differ from the given output in question

Comment: all are prime numbers except 12